# Weird Filter behavior

Tags: grails, grails-filters

I have created a folder named 'content' under grails-app/view and serve all gsp files from there which does not require a controller action.

In order to serve this view, I had added a UrlMapping  "/content/$view"(controller:"content").  This enables me to call /my-app/content/staticGSP directly without an actual ContentController.  This is working fine for some time without any issues.

Today, I wanted to add a filter which would redirect to a view under content folder directly.  I added a before closure in MYFilter.

```
  all(controller: "*") { 
       before = { 
             if(onSomeCond){ 
                 redirect(controller: 'content', action: 'seamless') 
                 return false 
             } 
            return true 
        } 
   }
```

This filter works fine if I try a Url `http://localhost:8080/my-app/home/index`.  Here I have a HomeController in my app. 
But, if I try `http://localhost:8080/my-app/content/anotherview`, then Filter just responds with a 404.  I am not able to figure out why this is.

Any insight would be really helpful.

Thanks, 
Abhijith

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `http://localhost:8080/my-app/content/anotherview` matches the url mapping `"/content/$view"(controller:"content")` and you do not have the view `anotherview` in `static` folder. `anotherview` is inside `content` folder. Hence, 404.

Is the name of the folder you added for static content is `content` or `static`? Your question says `static`

Comment: Apologies.  The folder name is 'content'.  I have updated the question.